# django -generated dynamic amount of forms and process

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a form that:
a) contains many forms of the same models that can be generated upon need.
b) a jquery script to generate the forms when needed just like the example bellow.
c) Handle all those forms in the view

When You click on the add button a new instance of the form is generated, is there any good tutorial on how to do that on django? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to have an AJAX call to a view that would return another form. The problem you would run into is that you will have to set unique prefixes for each form so that handling them later one will be doable.

In all honesty it is probably just easier to not use django-forms in this case. I have found on some of my projects that there are certain situations in which using django-forms ends up taking way more time and adds complexity to the project that isn't needed.

It is probably just easier to use jquery to add new form elements and then have the view that the form posts to just loop through the request.POST elements and handle them accordingly.